# Replacing a String in a List in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to replace a string in the list with another given string, using abstract list functions and lambda only.
The function consumes lst, a list of strings, str, the string you are replacing, and rep, the string you are replacing str with. 
Here is an example: 
(replace (list "hi" "how" "are" "you") "hi" "bye") -> (list "bye" "how" "are" "you")

Written below is the code that I wrote in recursion and it works.

```
(define (replace lst str rep)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [(equal? match (first lst))
           (cons rep (replace-all (rest lst) match rep))]
        [else (cons (first lst) (replace-all (rest lst) match rep))]))
```

Below that code is what I have tried but I'm not sure how to fix it to make it produce what I want.

```
(define (replace lst str rep)
   (map (lambda (x) (string=? x str)) lst))
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Almost there! you just have to ask, for each string: is this the one I want to replace? then replace it - otherwise leave it untouched:

```
(define (replace lst str rep)
  (map (lambda (x) (if (string=? x str) rep x)) 
       lst))
```

Comment: @Sania Did this post solve your question? if so, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the checkmark to its left ;) . Also worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).